# shouldn't return type of skimage.filters.threshold_mean be from 0-255?

Tags: machine-learning, image-processing, scikit-image

```
bw_image = sk_col.rgb2gray(image)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(3,3))
plt.imshow(bw_image, cmap="gray")
plt.show()

mean_val = threshold_mean(bw_image)

print('*****',mean_val,'******')

binary_image = bw_image > mean_val

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(3,3))
plt.imshow(binary_image, cmap="gray")
plt.title("Mean Threshold: " + str(mean_val))
plt.show()
```

[image: output images and threshold_mean]

The issue is why am I getting a mean of 0.386 . Shouldn't I get values around 0-255. skimage.color.rgb2gray function should return an image of pixel range 0-255. but when I print the pixels I see the values between 0 to 1. [image: Pixels returned by the rgb2gray function]

For this confusion I'm having trouble understanding how the binary image is found. Checked the documents of skimage.color, but didn't find anything helpful.

Comment: Turns out the answer is very straightforward. rgb2gray method returns the values after normalizing. It was time consuming to find the answer as it is not mentioned in the documentation and also I didn't find the answer in stackoverflow also. Now should I leave the question or delete it?

Comment: If you think it’ll be useful for a future visitor, post an answer to your question.

Comment: @AshrafulAlamImran thank you for your question. There is a page in the docs that does explain this, but it is perhaps not as easy to discover as it should be: https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/user_guide/data_types.html

In the future, we do hope to improve this behaviour, see https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/issues/3009 and https://mail.python.org/archives/list/scikit-image@python.org/thread/WUWDT3TBEJNPC6I3ZLXHXI3B4EU7JULV/

Answer (score 0):

skimage.color.rgb2gray(image) method returns the values after normalizing that's why all values are between 0-1. Answer was that simple.